# Hibernate join takes too long to work

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

Here is my problem:

I have this class it has few `@oneToMany` collections

```
public class ActivePropertyList implements Serializable 
{

 @OneToMany
 @JoinTable(name = "PropertyAttributeLink",
 joinColumns =
 @JoinColumn(name = "EANHotelID"),
 inverseJoinColumns =
 @JoinColumn(name = "AttributeID", referencedColumnName="AttributeID"))
 private Collection<AttributeList> attributeList;

 @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="EANHotelID")
 private Collection<Hotelimageslist> hotelimageslist;

 @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="EANHotelID")

 private Collection<Roomtypelist> roomtypelist;
//Getters & Setters ...
```

When I access this object from *XHTML* it takes too long to generate as I use `<ui:repeat value=#{controller.ActivePropertyList.attributeList}>` ...

PropertyAttributeLink has more than 5Mil rows and Images has more than 4Mil rows but when i use simple SQL query innerJoin i takes no more than few ms to generate Lists.

I've tried using namedQuery on AttributeList using HQL query but as AttributeList has no reference to ActivePropertyList as it is unidirectional `@oneToMany` it throws error on doing so.

Is there a way to create HQL NamedQuery to access each list just once and store it in controller?

something like

```
public List<AttributeList> getAttributeListByHotelID(int hotelID){
    Query q = session().createQuery("from AttributeList AL inner join PropertyAttributeLink PA where PA.hotelID=:hotelID");
    return q.list();
}
```

but this method doesn't work as hql needs AttributeList to know about PropertyAttributeLink

Answer (score 0):

Pointing the joins just make the atributtes available for where conditions and other stuff, you should use FETCH to make the relations eager and have it inmediatly, avoiding the lazy iniciators, something like

```
from AttributeList AL inner join FETCH PropertyAttributeLink PA where PA.hotelID=:hotelID
```

As you see isn't so hard, i hope that helps you, you can get more information, as always, in the docs [HQL - Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)